# Publish image to multiple registries using bootBuildImage

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle

I want to publish an image to multiple registries using springs integrated bootBuildImage task. I wonder if a can simply inherit from the builtIn BootBuildImage task, however I am not able to do it. Here is my gradle file:

```
tasks.withType<BootBuildImage> {
   imageName = "<my-custom-registry>"
   publish = true
}

tasks.named<BootBuildImage>("buildAndPublishDaimler") {
   imageName = "<my-other-custom-registry>"
   publish = true
   docker {
      publishRegistry {
        username = System.getenv("USERNAME")
        password = System.getenv("PASSWORD")
   }
}
```

However, the gradle task fails because I have to initialize all properties again in my second task.

What is the correct way to publish mutliple images using bootBuildImage?